# How to get contents of multilingual translated taxonomy terms in Views?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

My website is multilingual. There are about 40 taxonomy terms and each one is translated in to 3 languages. as an example:

```
term1_en, term1_fr,term1_it
```

I need to create a page to display contents that have a term which the taxonomy term ID (`tid`) is the Views contextual filter, but with the condition to return contents that have the same terms (synonym) in other languages. 
I mean if `node1` has `term1_en` and `node2` has term_fr, then if term1_en is passed as contextual filter both `node1` and `node2` must be returned because `node2` has its synonym in french.

how can I do that?

---

I can do this programmatically, by allowing multiple values be passed to contextual filter :

[image]

Then get the `tid`, load its synonyms in other languages and pass these terms to the Views contextual filter as an array, it is something like this (the basic idea)

```
$tid = %taxonomy:tid;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, "en").'+';  
$translated_term. = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, "fr").'+';  
$translated_term. = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, "it");  
$array = array($translated_term);
$view = views_get_view('myview');
$view->set_display("myblock");
$view->set_arguments($array);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

but I prefer not to use PHP and trying to do this via Views UI.